# Google Spreadsheet - Returning the closest value from a second column

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

In a google spreadsheet I have two columns A and B with different numbers from 0-200. 
Column A contain random numbers and Column B contain some values that are "known" in our system. Both list are order from the smallest value to the biggest.

What I want to do is to create a third column that return for each value in column A the closest value in column B

For example:

```
A   B   C

1   0   0

4   5   5

5   10  5

10  15  10

12  20  10
```

I used the following function 
**=VLOOKUP(B3,$J$3:$J$7,1,TRUE)**

but the problem is that it return the closest smaller number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data in columns A2:B, you can try in C2

```
=filter($B$2:$B$6, abs(A2-$B$2:$B$6)=min(abs(A2-$B$2:$B$6)))
```

and fill down.

[image: Example]